# State remain the same even the component unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a note editor using React and Draftjs. The problem I have now is that the state won't change even the component is unmounted and remain the same on the next render.

```js
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Proptype from "prop-types";
import Editor from 'draft-js-plugins-editor';
import {EditorState, ContentState} from "draft-js";
import CreateInlineToolbarPlugin from "draft-js-inline-toolbar-plugin";
import CustomInlineToolbar from "./CustomInlineToolbar";
import {updateTitle} from "../redux/action"

import "./NoteDetail.scss";
import 'draft-js-inline-toolbar-plugin/lib/plugin.css';

//TODOS: auto save function (need server)

const InlineToolbarPlugin = CreateInlineToolbarPlugin();
const {InlineToolbar} = InlineToolbarPlugin;

const NoteDetail = ({selectedNote, updateTitle}) => { 
    let {tags, note, _id, title} = selectedNote;
    let [titleState, setTitleState] = useState(title);
    let initContentState = ContentState.createFromText(note);
    let [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createWithContent(initContentState));
    let editorRef = useRef(React.createRef());


    const onContentChange = (state) => {
        setEditorState(state);
    }

    const focus = () => {
        editorRef.current.focus()
    }

    const synTitle = (state) => {
        updateTitle(state)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        synTitle(_id, titleState)
    }, [titleState, synTitle, _id])

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(titleState, title)
        console.log(editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText())
    },[title, editorState, titleState])


    return(
        <div>
            <div className="NoteDetail-container">
                <input type="text" id="title" 
                    value={titleState === "Untitled Page"? "":titleState} 
                    onChange={(e)=>setTitleState(e.target.value)}
                />
                {/* <div id="tags">{renderTags(tags)}</div> */}
                <div id="content" onClick={focus}>
                    <Editor 
                        plugins={[InlineToolbarPlugin]} 
                        onChange={onContentChange}
                        editorState={editorState}
                        ref={ele => editorRef.current = ele}
                    />
                    <CustomInlineToolbar InlineToolbar={InlineToolbar} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};



export default connect (null, {updateTitle})(NoteDetail)
```

I used the useEffect (the second one) to check if the props is passed properly. Here is the result:

```
NoteDetail.js:44 Untitled Page1 (titleState) Untitled Page1 (title)
NoteDetail.js:44 Hi (editorState)
NoteDetail.js:43 Untitled Page1 (titleState) Untitled Page (title)
NoteDetail.js:44 Hi (editorState)
```

even the props has changed, the state remain the same on every render. 
Can anyone help? I'll appreciate that

Comment: have you tried setting the states while using the props as dependencies of your useEffect? so that the new state change is made whenever the prop changes

Comment: yes, but it caused infinite loop. But shouldn't it be a new component when the parent parent component re-render and pass in different props?

Comment: that will cause a props change, but not a state change. It won't cause an infinite loop if you are not including the states as dependencies too.